# how can i upload app on google app engine on windows

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

Hello i want to know how can i upload my web app to google app engine on windows i have read through the documentation of google app engine and i can't upload it when i upload it i click deploy then it opens my web app on the a link like this

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=4/***************************lU0VoKrubEmg.8vh***************iIBeO6P2m_a3Qb0mQI#
```

but a go to the web app link and it hasn't been uploaded on linux i was uploading it using

```
appcfg.py -A projectid --oauth2 update project_directory
```

is there any alternative on windows ?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you try to deploy using `appcfg`?  Have you tried the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)?

Comment: i tried appcfg and when i open the url nothing happened

Comment: but the problem of localhost disappeard]

Comment: But when you run `appcfg update` does it give any errors?

Comment: no there is no errors and it tells me that the upload was sucessful

Comment: And what do the App Engine logs say? Are they showing a new deployed version? And 404s for your requests?

Comment: Thank you the problem has been solved it was my mistake the version existing on google app engine was different from the app i was uploading thank you